# Wrong number of arguments when calling .all on record which has enum_attr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

A MODEL1 has an account_type, so using the gem 'enumerated_attributes', I made the model as such:

```
class MODEL1 < ActiveRecord::Base

  enum_attr :account_type, %w(^live demo disabled)

  def is_live?
    self.account_type == :live
  end
  def is_not_live?
    self.account_type == :demo || self.account_type == :disabled
  end
end
```

The weird thing I don't understand is that when I query an arbitrary MODEL1 for seeds like this  (this is the error when I run the follwing command in the rubymine console, but this same 2 for 1 error happens during rake db:seed) :

```
MODEL1.all.sample
```

AND

```
MODEL1.all
```

I get this:

```
Dealer Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "MODEL1".* FROM "MODEL1S"
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@web/gems/enumerated_attribute-0.2.16/lib/enumerated_attribute/integrations/active_record.rb:78:in `instantiate'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@web/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/querying.rb:45:in `block in find_by_sql'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@web/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/result.rb:21:in `block in each'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@web/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/result.rb:21:in `each'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@web/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/result.rb:21:in `each'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@web/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/querying.rb:45:in `map'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@web/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/querying.rb:45:in `find_by_sql'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@web/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:585:in `exec_queries'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@web/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:471:in `load'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@web/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:220:in `to_a'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@web/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:49:in `sample'
from (irb):7
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@web/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@web/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@web/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
```

The model I'm trying to seed (where the error occurs during rake db:seed) is as such:

```
  model2 = Fabricate(:MODEL2, name: "Any MODEL2 Name #{n}", cost: n, MODEL1: MODEL1.all.sample)
```

in the MODEL2 model

```
belongs_to :MODEL1
```

and in the MODEL1 model

```
has_many :MODEL2s
```

in the migration, MODEL2

```
t.references :MODEL1
```

in the migration, MODEL1

```
t.enum :account_type
```

If there is an easier way to specify account_types for MODEL1, please let me know, I just need to be able to say MODEL1.all.sample or MODEL1.all

Comment: I looked at the source code at the top of your stack trace (see https://github.com/jeffp/enumerated_attribute/blob/84221b872f7f71152994b212520c833742a263e3/lib/enumerated_attribute/integrations/active_record.rb) and there is indeed a method call with two arguments at line 78, but I can't figure out for the life of me how the the method being called (`write_enumerated_attribute`) could have been defined with one.

Comment: Would it be easier to define account_type differently for MODEL1? I feel like it should be an enumerated attribute, but if there is an equally appropriate solution that doesn't yield this problem, I'm happy to try?

Comment: Your gem is 0.2.16 while on Github it's 0.3.1beta. May be try upgrading your gem?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are using Rails 4 which from the release notes:

> Model.all now returns an ActiveRecord::Relation, rather than an array of records. Use Relation#to_a if you really want an array. In some specific cases, this may cause breakage when upgrading.

So for starters you would want to call `to_a` on the model. But are you sure enumerated_attribute is rails 4 ready?

If you're not using postres I would recommend just using validates_inclusion_of, if you're using postgres check out https://coderwall.com/p/azi3ka